# Check and uncheck checkbox with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

In my form I have a table with checkbox in all of these columns. I have 3 `<tr>` and each `<tr>` has its `ng-repeate` calling the webservice to display the clones (Json data).
When I click on a checkbox I generate a js array which records id using this code :

```
checkoptions (array, model) {
angular.forEach(array, (value, key) => {
  if (array[key].checked) {
    model.push(array[key].id)
  }
})
```

And in HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="developer in $ctrl.developers">
    <td>{{developer.label}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{developer.id}}"
          ng-change="$ctrl.checkoptions($ctrl.developers,$ctrl.employees.developers)" 
             ng-model="developer.checked">
                <label for="{{developer.id}}"></label>
     </td>
```

It works, but the problem is that when I uncheck a checkbox it is not removed from the js array

Comment: Hey, maybe the [checklist-model directive](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) can help.

Comment: did you try  ng-checked ..? ,your question little bit confusing please post the html too

Comment: I prefer to find a solution without added module, thank
@Sajan it is done, thank

Comment: `ng-checked` is Angular native, isn't a additional module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included an else part to remove from the array:
http://jsfiddle.net/x9m1nqvp/1/

```
      $scope.checkoptions = function (array, model) {
        angular.forEach(array, (value, key) => {
          if (array[key].checked) {
            var index = model.indexOf(array[key].id);
            if(index == -1)
                model.push(array[key].id)
          }
          else {
            var index = model.indexOf(array[key].id);
            if(index >=0)
                model.splice(index, 1);
          }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

While Everton's answer gets the job done, it is a bit redundant checking every item in the array, every time a single checkbox changes state. You don't really have to update for every single item in the array.

Here is an example, where only the checkbox that's actually toggled, is added or removed from the `employees.developers` array (*Note: no need for the redundant `angular.forEach`*):

```
$scope.checkoption = function (developer){
    if (developer.checked) {
        var index = $scope.employees.developers.indexOf(developer.id);
        if(index == -1)
            $scope.employees.developers.push(developer.id)
    } else {
        var index = $scope.employees.developers.indexOf(developer.id);
        if(index >=0)
            $scope.employees.developers.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

and how this is used in the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="developer in developers">
    <td>{{developer.label}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{developer.id}}"
            ng-change="checkoption(developer)" 
            ng-model="developer.checked">
        <label for="{{developer.id}}"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
```